# What are best books, programes and sites to improve Texas Hold'em (Limit and No Limit) skills?

Tags: texas-hold-em, learning

What are best computer programes and web sites one should use to upgrade Texas Hold'em (Limit and No Limit) skills? There are thousands of books, hundreds of web pages a many programes to teach poker. Houw could beginer can find which are good and which are bad?

I am interest in learning game itself, that means knowing probabilities, when to rise, when to fold. How to handle standard situations in game. How to find a fish. I am not interesten in budget management (the good tips like do not use all your money in one game can be easily found).

Answer with few examples of those categories with simple reasons why they are chosed will be accepted.

Comment: This question is way too broad at the moment. For a start you didnt even mention which form of Poker you were wanting too learn. If you have specific questions about what you would like to learn then please ask them individually.

Comment: When you say programes - do you mean software applications or TV shows?

Comment: I mean software applications but good TV shows will be appreciated.

Comment: Again, as gaz said, this is just way too broad. It could potentially be split into 3+ separate questions. You just won't get a useful answer asking a question like this here.

Comment: Ok I will find a time and I will split it to 3 questions.

Comment: First one http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/what-are-best-books-for-newbie-medium-and-advanced-level-players-in-order-to-le

Comment: Second http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/what-are-recommended-computer-programs-for-learning-no-limit-texas-holdem

Comment: Third http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/what-are-good-web-sites-to-learn-no-limit-texas-holdem